# how do I change the change list name in a loop

Tags: python, excel, tensorflow

I'm trying to minimize this to further add more data from excel into these lists.

```
 for column in range(1, 26):
    #setting limit to number of row
    row_num=1
    train0_position = sheet.cell(1, column)
    train0.append(train0_position.value)

    train1_position = sheet.cell(2, column)
    train1.append(train1_position.value)

    train2_position = sheet.cell(3, column)
    train2.append(train2_position.value)

    train3_position = sheet.cell(4, column)
    train3.append(train3_position.value)

    train4_position = sheet.cell(5, column)
    train4.append(train4_position.value)

    train5_position = sheet.cell(6, column)
    train5.append(train5_position.value)

    train6_position = sheet.cell(7, column)
    train6.append(train6_position.value)

    train7_position = sheet.cell(8, column)
    train7.append(train7_position.value)

    train8_position = sheet.cell(9, column)
    train8.append(train8_position.value)

    train9_position = sheet.cell(10, column)
    train9.append(train9_position.value)

    train10_position = sheet.cell(11, column)
    train10.append(train10_position.value)

    train11_position = sheet.cell(12, column)
    train11.append(train11_position.value)

    train12_position = sheet.cell(13, column)
    train12.append(train12_position.value)

    train13_position = sheet.cell(14, column)
    train13.append(train13_position.value)

    train14_position = sheet.cell(15, column)
    train14.append(train14_position.value)

    train15_position = sheet.cell(16, column)
    train15.append(train15_position.value)'''
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably:

```
for i in range(1, 26):
    setattr(self, "train"+str(i), sheet.cell(i+1, column))
```

But you could use a dictionary instead of all these variables